# На андроид Api >= 23 получаю Attempt to get length of null array . Пытаюсь получить список каталогов в директории

Tags: java, android

Была подключена библиотека https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-file-dialog/

Простенький файловый менеджер. Он исправно работает на других апи. А на апи 27 ошибка. Вот кусочек лога, где указывается на ошибку.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                                   at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1432)
                                                                                   at com.lamerman.FileDialog.getDirImpl(FileDialog.java:194)
                                                                                   at com.lamerman.FileDialog.getDir(FileDialog.java:169)
                                                                                   at com.lamerman.FileDialog.onCreate(FileDialog.java:128)
```

И сам кусок кода: 
 ругается на первую строку

```
 Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {
                return lhs.getPath().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getPath());
            }
        });
```

Вот весь метод целиком, тут инициализируется files

```
    private void getDirImpl(final String dirPath) {
    currentPath = dirPath;

    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    File f = new File(currentPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    // Null if file is not a directory
    if (files == null) {
        currentPath = PATH_ROOT;
        f = new File(currentPath);
        files = f.listFiles();
    }

    // Sort files by alphabet and ignore casing
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {
            return lhs.getPath().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getPath());
        }
    });

    dialog.setTitle(currentPath);

    /*
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090915/show-songs-from-sdcard
     * http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory
     */
    if (currentPath.equals(PATH_ROOT)) {
        boolean mounted = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

        if (mounted) {
            addItem(mList, PATH_SDCARD + "(SD Card)", this.options.iconSDCard);
            path.add(PATH_SDCARD);
        }
    }

    if (!currentPath.equals(PATH_ROOT)) {
        addItem(mList, "/ (Root folder)", this.options.iconUp);
        path.add(PATH_ROOT);

        addItem(mList, "../ (Parent folder)", this.options.iconUp);
        path.add(f.getParent());
        parentPath = f.getParent();
    }

    ArrayList<File> listDirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    ArrayList<File> listFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listDirs.add(file);
        }
        // Only add files if we're not in folder mode
        else if (!options.selectFolderMode) {
            listFiles.add(file);
        }
    }

    for (File dir : listDirs) {
        path.add(dir.getPath());
        addItem(mList, dir.getName(), this.options.iconFolder);
    }

    for (File file : listFiles) {
        path.add(file.getPath());
        addItem(mList, file.getName(), this.options.iconFile);
    }

    SimpleAdapter fileList = new SimpleAdapter(this, mList,
        R.layout.file_dialog_row,
        new String[] { ITEM_KEY, ITEM_IMAGE },
        new int[] { R.id.fdrowtext, R.id.fdrowimage }
    );

    fileList.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listview.setAdapter(fileList);
}
```

я ошибся, не работает так же и на апи 24. На 19 работает. Продебажил, посмотрел в чем разница и вот результат.

Дебаг на апи 27: https://gyazo.com/55023ea2dd1b073d7306a0287bfd7d77
Как видите при первом запуске, приходит корневая директория "/" .
  здесь `f : "/"`

```
File f = new File(currentPath);
```

здесь files получается null.

```
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

Дебаг на апи 19: https://gyazo.com/8b41e11a90d4ff607f35d63e8057fc6d
то же самое , только files не null
 здесь `f : "/"`

```
File f = new File(currentPath);
```

здесь files: File[33]@831435427480.

```
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

Я подумал, что может директория "/" в новых апи не воспринимается как корневая. И создал

```
File f = new `File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath())
```

но `f.listFiles()` мне снова вернул null. 
Теперь думаю, я должен быть убежден, что дело не в отсутствии такой директории или доступа к ней. Разрешение на запись на флешку в манифесте есть. На запись в внутреннюю память или на её чтение, разрешения не требуются.

Comment: Нашел в документации изменения нового андроида, там есть и насчет массивов что то. Понять пока не могу https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html

Comment: Лучше покажите участок кода в котором инициализируется переменная `files`.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, прикрепил весь метод, переменная локальная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что на api >= 23 новые правила: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request

Теперь  разрешения написанные в манифесте, требуются не перед установкой, а во время работы приложения. Нужно какое то разрешение, спрашиваешь у пользователя (его ответ запоминается, но он в настройках приложения может отозвать разрешение в любой момент, т.е. теперь стоит учитывать это и менять поведение приложения, быть готовым к отказу). Так же и для ваших приложений написанных ранее, для Api ниже 23: пользователь андроид 6 уже может отозвать любое разрешение и у таких приложений. 
 В общем это всё грамотно расписано в документации.

Для удобства и красоты кода , объявил парочку таких переменных

```
 public final String[] EXTERNAL_PERMS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
public final int EXTERNAL_REQUEST = 138;
```

Парочку таких методов:

```
 public boolean canAccessExternalSd() {
        return (hasPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
    }

    private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
        return (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm));
    }
```

и в нужный мне момент вызываю

```
 public boolean requestForPermission() {
        boolean isPermissionOn = true;
        final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (version >= 23) {
            if (!canAccessExternalSd()) {
                isPermissionOn = false;
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, EXTERNAL_PERMS, EXTERNAL_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        return isPermissionOn;
    }
```

и теперь `listFiles();` мне больше не возвращает null, так как я получил разрешение, но надо менять код и подготовить к тому, что делать если разрешение не будет получено.