# java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, android, исключения

при вызове

```
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

получаю ошибку `java.lang.SecurityException:`

в манифесте прописано

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
```

в чем причина?

Comment: на каком андроид пробуете ? апи выше 23?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759200/208242 ,прочитайте о том как получать разрешения, если api >= 23 . Теперь недостаточно прописать разрешения в манифесте, их надо обрабатывать в во время исполнения кода